# Visual Studio Code follow link (Ctrl + click) opens it in the editor instead of opening it in the browser

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, kde-plasma

When a file opened in Visual Studio Code, it contains a link, and it is possible to follow the link with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click.

Usually the link is opened with the default browser, but for the past few weeks the link have been downloaded and displayed in Visual Studio Code.

Is there a way to get the default behavior back?

I use Visual Studio Code on [Kubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu).

Comment: Did you try disabling all extensions? It is possible your extensions might be doing something weird. Also, I would try resetting preferences, just in case that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

This *alternative way* helped me:)

Go to Google Chrome → *Settings* → *Default browser* → *Set Google Chrome as default browser*.

Comment: Yes it was a default browser issue ! thanks ! I'm on Kubuntu and the default browser was set to "open in application based on URL content". So links to js files were opened in vscode. Bounty is for you !!!

Answer (score 0):

The action needed to fix this will vary based on file type that has the link.

For Markdown files try the following:

In Visual Studio Code: menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings* → search for 'link' → under Extensions, find *Markdown* → under "Markdown, Links:Open Location", select the gear icon and click "Reset Settings".

If not Markdown, explore other categories and find similar settings based on the installed extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I am using alt-shift-right to select file name, ctrl-c, ctrl-o, ctrl-v, enter